Probability - counting twice
If we have a problem like this:
Consider two independent random variables
$X \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$
and
$Y \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$
with probability distributions
$Pr[X = k] = \frac{1}{6} \quad \text{for all } k \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$
$Pr[Y = k] = \frac{1}{8} \quad \text{for all } k \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$
Evaluate the following statement about the random variable $( Z = X + Y )$
$P(Z>5)$
Then we find all the $X+Y > 5$. This is 38 out of 48 possible. When doing that, we get for example $X+Y= 6$ by saying $1+5$ AND $5+1$. In total there are 11 duplicates of X+Y>5.
My question: Should they be included in the total, or should they be subtracted like this $38-11 = 27$?

The events $(X,Y)=(5,1)$ and $(X,Y)=(1,5)$ are not the same!   If you want to identify the events, you need to be careful since unordered events like ${1,1}$ or ${1,8}$ do not have the same probability as ${1,2}$.

To stress: while there may be many ways to model the sample space, computationally it is convenient if all the outcomes have the same probability.  Viewed as ordered pairs, then event $(a,b)$ has probability $\frac 1{48}$  for all the possible $(a,b)$ (so $1≤a≤6$ and $1≤b≤8$).   That means that all you have to do is count the number of ordered pairs that satisfy your test.

Question 1 : What is the probability to have $Z>5$ ?  Question 2 : What is the probability to have $Z \le 5$ ? Question 3 : check that the total is $1$.
